# Python command line 'file input stream'

Tags: python, file, file-io, filestream

I'm fairly new to python coming from C/C++, I was wondering how I would get my 'main.py' to reconize/use the imput given from a bash shell as:

> python main.py < text.txt

(the file is in plain text)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read from `sys.stdin`:

```
import sys
sys.stdin.read()
```

Being a [file-like object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects), you can use its reading functions or simply iterate over the input lines:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

Comment: @walter use `line = line.rstrip()`.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `fileinput` module would be most appropriate here, and more flexible.

http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

In addition to supporting stdin, it can also read from files listed as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) to create an option parser that accepts a file path and opens it.

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('infile', type='open')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    for line in args.infile:
        print line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If `type='open'` does not provide enough control, it can be replaced with `argparse.FileType('o')` which accepts `bufsize` and `mode` args (see http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#type)

**EDIT:** My mistake. This will **not** support your use case. This will allow you to provide a filepath, but not pipe the file contents into the process. I'll leave this answer here as it might be useful as an alternative.